# stan: input data for arrays of vectors

Tags: vector, input, stan

I am fairly new to stan and I am trying to read in some data for my model.
I defined an array of vectors as proposed in the corresponding stan manual but I don't know how to write down my input data.
The data parameters I need look like this:

```
data {
   int         K;  // number classes
   int         N;  // number of all data points
   vector[2] y[N];
}
```

For a normal vector vector[k] my input looks like this:

```
K <- 5
N <- 2
y <- c(8.90680694580078,5.51890277862549)
```

But I just don't know how to do this for the sort of vector I have.
Something like this doesn't work for N <- 4

```
y <- c(c(8.90680694580078,5.51890277862549), c(2.00219345092773,10.7796802520752))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In R, you need to pass a matrix with `N` rows and 2 columns or I believe it would work to pass a list with `N` elements, each of which is a vector of length 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a matrix

```
y <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol = 2)
```